# Beginner to JQuery, "Draggable" not dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a program which simulates Scrabble, allowing the user to drag tile pieces to make words for points. However, I am having an issue with the JQuery 'Draggable' function.
I'm thinking it might have to do with how I'm importing the JQuery, but I'm struggling to find a way to test it.

(Also, apologies if the formatting for my question is off. First-time user!)

**index.html**:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="js/draggable.js"></script>
<title>Scrabble - Nicholas W</title>
</head>

<!-- Some additional irrelevant code here -->

<body>
<div id=pieces class="draggable ui-widget-content">
<p>Piece1</p>
<p>Piece2</p>
<p>Piece3</p>
</div>
</body>
```

**draggable.js**

```
$( function() {
console.log("Trying to drag...")
$( ".draggable" ).draggable();
} );
```

Comment: Please check this line `<script type="js/draggable.js"></script>`. I think you're referencing the library incorrectly, you might wanna replace the `type` with `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript selector was not picking the P tag below the class. Also you are selecting a class, so the return is an array and you need to .each() over them.
See the snippet, now working

```js
$(function() {
console.log("Trying to drag...");
$( ".draggable p" ).each(function(){
  $(this).draggable();
  });
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=pieces class="draggable ui-widget-content">
<p>Piece1</p>
<p>Piece2</p>
<p>Piece3</p>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact functionality you are looking for can be found here: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Check out the last 2 boxes that snap to a grid